# Acessando um JSON com JS

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-datatables

Estava tentando acessar um JSON com JS, eis um **exemplo** de como eles são:

```
{
  status: "0",
  ano: "Não Informado",
  competencia: "Não Informado",
  id_Publication: "8"
}
```

Mas na verdade essa é somente uma parte do JSON completo. Esse é "*um array multidimensional*". Como eu posso acessar as informações dentro de **p**, mais especificamente a parte da competência?

Já tentei usar esse código:

```
{
  targets: 7,
  data: "",
  render: function(data, type, full){
    returnconsole.log(full);
  }
}
```

Ele retorna todo o JSON se uso dessa maneira e se coloco:

```
{
  targets: 7,
  data: "",
  render: function(data, type, full){
    returnconsole.log(full['p']);
  }
}
```

Ele retorna os dados somente de p, **MAS** se eu tento colocar:

```
{
  targets: 7,
  data: "",
  render: function(data, type, full){
    returnconsole.log(full['p.competencia']);
  }
}
```

Ele retorna *undefined*.

Comment: Esse JSON não é valido. Corrige o mesmo para que possamos responder, está bem confuso, valida ele aqui: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: É válido sim, funciona aqui, isso é um exemplo, como eu posso acessá-lo? @LeonardoBonetti

Comment: Agora sim está válido. Vou postar a resposta !

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar um objeto do seu JSON `myObj ={json aqui}` e acessar pelo nome do objeto ponto atributo: `myObj.competencia`. Simples, fácil e rápido.

```js
myObj = {status: "0", ano: "Não Informado", competencia: "Não Informado", id_Publication: "8"};

console.log(myObj.competencia)
```